# Java program amendment to correct the maths output. Help needed.

Tags: java, methods, factorial

Hi I have built this code but when you run option 2 I need it to output the answer so that it prints the factorial in this form - factorial of 5 is 5*4*3*2*1 = 120 (for example). If someone could amend my code I would appreciate it greatly.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LO1v5 {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter your full name: ");

        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String me = null;




        try {
            me = br.readLine();
        } 

        catch (final IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error trying to read your name");
            System.exit(1);

        }

        menu(me);

    }


    public static void menu(String me) {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Thank you, " + me +".");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println ("Please choose from one of the following options:");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1 = create new user");
        System.out.println("2 = do maths");
        System.out.println("3 = exit");

        int choice = 0;

        final Scanner scanchoice = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (choice != 3) {

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter \"1\", \"2\" or \"3\":");

            choice = scanchoice.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {
            case 1:  string_function(me);
            break;
            case 2:  number_function();
            break;
            case 3:  System.out.println("Thanks for using this program");
            System.exit(0);

            break;

            default: System.out.println("I am sorry, please enter 1, 2 or 3");

            break;

            }

        }

    }

    public static void string_function(String me) {

        System.out.println("Thank you " + me + ". Enter name to recieve new username: ");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String user = null; 

        try {  
            user = br.readLine();
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) {  
            System.out.println("Error trying to read your name");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        create_username(user);  

    }



    private static void number_function() {


        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number whose factorial is to be found: ");
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            result = result * i;
        }


        System.out.println("The factorial of " + n + " is " + result);


    }



    private static void create_username(String user) {

        String fullName = null;

        int spacePos = user.indexOf(" ");
        int length = user.length();

        String firstName = user.substring(0, 1);
        String secondInitial = user.substring(spacePos+1, length);
        fullName = firstName.concat(secondInitial);

        System.out.println("Hello.  Your username is " + fullName);





    }
}
```

Comment: "If someone could amend my code I would appreciate it greatly." Stack Overflow is not a free code correction service. Do a search on string concatenation, try to implement it and only post if you run into a specific programming problem.

Comment: OK then can you explain it to me?

Comment: Stack Overflow is also not a remedial programming school. Do you know how to use a search engine? Can you read? String concatenation. Start there. This is where your code is bollocked: int result = 1; for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { result = result * i;  }

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void number_function() {
       ...       
       String label = "";
       String prefix = "";
       for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
           result = result * i;
           label += prefix + (n - i + 1);
           prefix = " * ";
       }

       System.out.println("The factorial of " + n + " is " + label + " = " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static void number_function() {


    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number whose factorial is to be found: ");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int result = 1;
    String s ="";
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        result = result * i;
        if (i ==1)
            s += n + "*";
        else if(i < n)
            s += n-(i-1) + "*";
        else if(i == n)
            s += n-(i-1);
    }   

     // changed " is " to    " = "
    System.out.println("The factorial of " + s + " = " + result);
    // Or if you dont want the words "The factorial of " then use line below
    System.out.println(s + " = " + result);


}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I really need it to print the result like this...
The factorial of 5 is 5*4*3*2*1 = 120
The factorial of 4 is 4*3*2*1 = 24
etc. How would I do that?

Answer (score -1):

```
 int n = 5; 
 int result = 1;
 for ( int i = n ; i >= 1 ; i--){
   result = result * i;
   if ( i == 1) {
     cout << i << " = " ;
     break;
   }else{
      cout << i << " * " ;
   }
 } 
 cout << result << endl;
```

Comment: Sorry guys that doesnt seem to be giving me the "5*4*3*2*1" I need to show in my output?

Comment: Could you paste in the whole method as I might be adding the code wrong.

Comment: I'm just using 5 as an example, its whatever number the user inputs.

Comment: @Jesse vang Thank you so much. I need it to print out this as the answer though..
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120.